# SQL Injection Compromised site?

Tags: security, sql-injection

This may sound like a weird question but is there any where I can download a website that is vulnerable to sql injection the url kind not login bypass?

I'm making a vulnerability scanner and I want to learn some SQLi so i can include it in my project.

Thanks, it doesn't need to be fancy. Just enough to practice on.

Comment: It's just as easy to make your own.

Comment: -1, +flag: *I'm making a vulnerability scanner* followed immediately by *Honestly, I don't know enough php and I don't know how to use the things like www.example.com/id=2 (the id=2 part)*, simply screams **script kiddie alert!** If your making a presentation for class, just say so. If you're trying to teach yourself how to become a l33t h@><or d00dz, find a new hobby.

Comment: What? No, my school is too poor to have anything associated with computer science. I am interested in pen testing as a carer. Am I a script kiddie? I like to hope not ;) but i would say no because I like to code my own tools and I'm not just doing this so i show my friends how im a l33t h4xxor. I have a genuine interest in how computers and networking works. So please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[OWASP WebGoat](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_WebGoat_Project) is the usual example. Includes SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: +1 - OWASP should always be the first port of call when it comes to web security.

Comment: Thats pretty cool but do i have to go through all the lessons or can I just exploit the SQLi and do the others later?

Comment: In the end I read up on php GET and decided to make my own, not as hard as expect. All though webGoat looks really fun to play with.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot download their site to test for injection vulnerabilities. You need to download their whole DB and configs to do what you are saying. If you want to *benevolently* go checking the security of various sites, you have to ask them about their system and model it on your own. OWASP works on systems not recently updated with patches, like the comment of tackline-its a first port.

Comment: I didn't expect to download a real hosted site. I had expect that someone at some point had made a pack of the files needed to locally host a vulnerable site to use as your own security playground.

Comment: very very few would pack it and send it to you, especially if you want to 'test' their vulnerabilities.

Comment: No. You don't understand. I mean a pack of files that were designed to be broken with built in vulnerabilitys. Just looks at WebGoat, that's exactly what I mean. Even if webgoat works on unpatched systems I want to learn sql injection in a legal enviorment.

Answer (score 0):

OWAPS's WebGoat is an application that is built to be vulnerable to attack,  it is a simulation of real world vulnerabilities.  [The Whitebox](http://code.google.com/p/thewhitebox/) is a collection of real world vulnerabilities,  it has 2 web applications that where abandoned because the applications where so insecure.  It also has a set of challenges there are vulnerable code snips taken from real world applications.   This project has real world sql injection as well more serious vulnerabilities.

Try scanning the vulnerable apps with Wapiti (open source) or Acunetix ($) or NTOSpider($$$).   Then try using the applications, create blog posts ect,  and then scan it again.

Also check out [Damn Vulnerable Linux](http://www.damnvulnerablelinux.org/)  and [Google Jarlsburg](http://google-gruyere.appspot.com/).